# Cannot use the same external js file for two buttons (in different views)

Tags: jquery, button, onclick, jquery-events

I have following button on my view:

```
<td>    
<?php 
$data = array(
    'name' => $id,
    'class' => 'do_the_job',
    'content' => 'Do the job'
             );
echo form_button($data);
?>    
</td>
```

When I click on that button it does what I expected because I have the following function in my EXTERNAL JS file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".do_the_job").click(function() {
   //does the job
});
});
```

I have also another controller and view and I created the button (with same class) for it dynamically using jQuery:

```
table.html('<button name="'+id+'" class="do_the_job">Do the job</button>');
```

The problem is that when I click on that button, it does not work despite the fact that the button has the same class as the first button and it is expected to do the work as it is described in my EXTERNAL JS file.

I have researched and saw that I should use the function `on()` instead of `click()`. I have modified my external JS file in the following way but it still does not work:

```
$(".do_the_job").on("click", function() {      
   //does the job
});
```

Could you please help me to solve the problem?

Comment: wrong use of `on` for delegated events...see docs. There are 2 ways to use it and you need the delegation approach. Also class in selector is different in second example

Comment: thanks. I corrected the class selector in second example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because of direct event listener.In your case you may consider delegated event listener.

For example if you have Html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button type="button" id="foo" class ="dothisjob" >Foo</button>
<button type="button" id="bar" class ="dothisjob" >Bar</button> 
</body>
</html>
```

and if your event listener written like this

```
$(".dothisjob").on("click", function() {...});
```

this will handle only click event of static classes which was aadded at page load.(direct event listener)

this click event listener won't work for if you add `class='dothisjob'` dynamically such as
`addclass('dothisjob') toggleclass('dothisjob')`.

**In order to handle  event listeners for dynamically added classes you should use delegated event listeners .**

To achieve that you should give the responsibility to some static elements of your page.(delegated event listener)

```
$("body").on("click", ".dothisjob", function() {...});
```

Now body is responsible to listen the events. If you add .dothisjob dynamically to one of the child elements of body this will work.

[Useful SO answer Direct vs. Delegated - jQuery .on()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8111171/3186681)

Answer (score 1):

In your use case you want to use the `on` differently, you're still binding your event like using the `click` method(assuming `add_to_trip` is what you formerly referred to as `do_the_job`). What you want is:

```
$("#static_parent_element").on(
    "click",
    ".add_to_trip",
    function () {/*Do the job*/}
);
```

This checks propagating events from elements in the static container against the given *matcher*, allowing you to add and remove elements dynamically.